# Solr 5 custom field and filter

Tags: solr, solr5

I'm new to solr. After i tried using Solr 5 client. I want to try Solr 5 source code. 
So my questions are,

1. can i create a custom field for my own core on solr 5 by editing
   schema.xml?  if it's possible, please tell me the location (it wasn't in my conf folder, should i create a new one?).
2. Is there any other method for adding a custom field other than using schema
   api?
3. Everytime i try to create a new core and then index the files, there are only `currency.xml`, `elevate.xml`, `managed-schema`(generated schema), `params.json`, `protwords.txt`, `solrconfig.xml`, `stopwords.txt` `synonyms.txt` on my `conf` folder and there's no `schema.xml`. Did i miss something?
4. Is there any simple tutorial to explain the custom filter on solr 5?

I really appriciate your answer. Thank's

Answer (score 1):

When you create a core in Solr 5 it comes by default with schemaless mode active. This mode make solr schema not visible and all changes need to be done with schema API. If you want to manage schema by yourself you could rename `managed-schema` to `schema.xml` and modify `solrconfig.xml` to not use schemaless mode. In `solrconfig.xml` replace

```
 <schemaFactory class="ManagedIndexSchemaFactory">
   <bool name="mutable">true</bool>
   <str name="managedSchemaResourceName">managed-schema</str>
 </schemaFactory>
```

by

```
 <schemaFactory class="ClassicIndexSchemaFactory"/>
```

Now solr will use `schema.xml` managed by yourself.

The only mandatory configuration files to use are `solrconfig.xml` and in your case `schema.xml`. The other files are used just if you configure some filters using them. If you are using the example `schema.xml` probably you need to have all these files. But clean the configuration files to have just the fields and field types you really expect to use.

To learn more about filters, tokenizers and analyzers you can take a look at https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes
2. Manually editing the schema and using the API, are only two ways, as far as i know.
3. How exactly are you creating this core? Are you using the install_solr_service.sh ? Assuming its a linux system, check /var/solr/configs folder. Thats where the config files are if you ran that script.
4. Yes of course :) . https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Apache+Solr+Reference+Guide  There is a "Getting Started" section, which should answer all your questions, including where configs are stored, how to use them etc.

Happy Searching!

Comment: thx for you answer, now i have passed the schema thingy. Now i want to add a custom filter for my field. Let say, during indexing i want to check if the item contains a word. I already decided to use standard tokenizer. Does solr have a tutorial about this? I already checked this one http://solr.pl/en/2013/02/04/developing-your-own-solr-filter-part-2/ but i couldn't understand the code